# Stack Overflow Documentation: Request an Improvement not useful

Tags: discussion, documentation

The "request an improvement" button just acts like the "flag" button on normal Stack Overflow, instead of giving a text field to actually request an improvement.

For example, let's say somebody gives a completely valid example, but does something which may have bad side effects. Then I should be able to request an improvement, "Hi, your example works fine here, but it may be insecure on a system with login for unprivileged users, who could read the file you're creating, try to add something to avoid the problem".

This is currently not possible. I could only flag it as an unhelpful example, which is not what I want to request.

So there should be an option "write some suggestions for the author(s)" with a text area next to it.

Comment: ... or just a comments system, as we have here.

Comment: I think you're allowed to add a (very brief) comment if you downvote instead of flagging.  (Or maybe it's the other way around, I don't remember -- point is, they do different things.)

Comment: There are text boxes for flag for improvement requests that do allow you to enter in comments. Should open up under each flag category when you click radio. I have used them quite a bit. Not suggesting the UI is not confusing or that it is intuitive though

Comment: The problem is, that the whole "flag" mechanism is no "request something" mechanism, but a "report something as bad" mechnism, which is incorrect for requesting some improvment to something already quite good.

Answer (score 1):

Just downvote the example, this is equivalent to flagging for improvement (obviously?) and will give you the option of writing a short comment with the improvement request you have.

Comment: @Justin Does undownvoting keep the request?

Comment: No, it does not. I was mislead by the user interface.

Comment: sounds good in principle but flag sets item into "needs improvement" list in dash of that tag and down-vote doesn't seem to allow comment.  UI is confusing

Comment: Downvote would mean "wrong, horribly insecure, etc." for me. I rather want to say "That's nice as it is, but please have a look here and there and try to improve a bit for an even better example". So "Request an Improvement" should be exactly this: A request form.